# I get error Undefined symbols for architecture i386: when running my program

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

I am trying to add a gif to my image view, so following instructions off the web, I imported the `FLAnimatedImage` and `FLAnimatedImageView` classes I downloaded. I added them to a group in my project, selected copy, and used Those classes. Now I get 15 errors, described below.

The description part is the :

```
Ld "/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iMark_OS-dmxhnswrkktqsacxqtlldejutoqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iMark OS.app/iMark OS" normal i386
    cd "/Users/mark/Desktop/Xcode Projects/iMark OS"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iMark_OS-dmxhnswrkktqsacxqtlldejutoqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iMark_OS-dmxhnswrkktqsacxqtlldejutoqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iMark_OS-dmxhnswrkktqsacxqtlldejutoqb/Build/Intermediates/iMark OS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iMark OS.build/Objects-normal/i386/iMark OS.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iMark_OS-dmxhnswrkktqsacxqtlldejutoqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iMark OS.app/iMark OS"
```

And the error part is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CACurrentMediaTime", referenced from:
      ___42-[FLAnimatedImage addFrameIndexesToCache:]_block_invoke_2 in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceCopyProperties", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
      -[FLAnimatedImage predrawnImageAtIndex:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateWithData", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceGetCount", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_CGImageSourceGetType", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CADisplayLink", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FLAnimatedImageView.o
  "_UTTypeConformsTo", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kUTTypeGIF", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: FYI - you get the linker error when you build your app, not run it.

Comment: Looks like you need to at least add the `ImageIO` framework to your project.

Comment: @rmaddy that worked, but now I get, `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CACurrentMediaTime", referenced from:
      ___42-[FLAnimatedImage addFrameIndexesToCache:]_block_invoke_2 in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CADisplayLink", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FLAnimatedImageView.o
  "_UTTypeConformsTo", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
  "_kUTTypeGIF", referenced from:
      -[FLAnimatedImage initWithAnimatedGIFData:] in FLAnimatedImage.o
… I had to remove the last part
`

Comment: Add the `QuartzCore` framework.

Comment: And probably the `MobileCoreServices` framework.

Answer (score 14):

I figured it out. There were 3 missing frameworks, QuartzCore,ImageIO, and MobileCoreServices. for any future viewers who have the same problem, you look in the .h and .m files to see what frameworks they import. Images:

.h:[image: .h file import]
.m[image: .m file import]

Then, you click on project, go into build phases, link binary with libraries, and add the frameworks for both your project and projecttest . not really sure if you have to add for both of them. Well, that worked for me, so hopefully it works for other people.

Comment: Yes, usually these type of compiler errors are due to missing frameworks.

Comment: Bingo. Was doing FB SDK upgrades and this did the trick for me. Thanks!